# Problem enabling Native Client (NaCl) in Chromium

Tags: 12.10, chromium

In *chrome://flags* I've enabled Native Client and started Chromium with

```
chromium-browser --enable-nacl
```

I've installed [one of the demo apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bullet-physics-nacl-test/pgehkhceingafmkkmbeoempaablkkeal), but when I run it it says "No plug-in available to display this content." I've also tried enabling the Portable Native Client.

I'm running 12.10 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appears from http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109989 that NaCl works if you download the official google version and not the Ubuntu distributed package (lame).

Comment: The Ubuntu distribution also had a bug in the tab bar recently (it was collapsing with only one tab open). I'll stick with the official distribution from now on. I added it to my apt sources by following these instructions. http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome